# Updating view after AJAX post without reload

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, laravel

I trying to reload a div's content after an AJAX post, I really have no clue about how to do this. I know that I have to update the innerhtml with Jquery but I am stuck here.

```
/* ----------------------------------------------
    Like/Dislike
-----------------------------------------------*/

$('.like').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    postId = event.target.dataset['postid'];

    console.log(postId)
    console.log(token) 
    console.log(urlLike)

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: urlLike,
        data: {postId: postId, _token: token},
    })
    .done(function(msg) {
        console.log(msg); // 
    });
```

This is my html at the moment, with a normal reload the like count gets updated and with a simple if statement the  gets an class with active if the post is liked by the user.
How would I update this span class after the AJAX call?

```
<div class="wis-numbers">
   <?php $likes = $post->likes->count() ?>
       <span style="cursor: pointer;" class="like @if( $post->isLiked ) active @endif" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}" data-original-title="{{ $likes }} vind ik leuks" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"><i class="zmdi zmdi-thumb-up" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}"></i> {{ $likes }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put it inside the callback

```
$('.like').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var postId = event.target.dataset['postid'],
        $counter = $('.wis-numbers span');
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: urlLike,
        data: {postId: postId, _token: token},
        success: function(response) {
                $counter.html(response); // if this is an object change to the value you want
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If the POST body already returns the new count, that could be used instead of the blind increment. This might more easily handle the case where the button is a toggle.

Comment: The first way you had it is also good, in cases where the OP doesn't have much control over the server, and the server doesn't send any data in the response body (not totally uncommon for POST).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/)
This library updates the view without reloading the page..

The this you have to do is - just send/get the required data from Ajax and just after ajax response update the vue data source, then its the responsibility of vue.js to update the whole page (without reloading) whichever DOM element is using that particular data-source.
Hope this helps you. Thank You!

Comment: I stumbled across Vue.js before, it looks very promising before, I'll take a look at it. Eventually, I have got figured this out with some 'cheating' on the front end. I basically recreate the state of a liked post and inject it using jquery after a success response from the backend. When the user reloads the page the templating engine takes over and displays the right html.